# Criar um array com objetos no Javascript

Tags: javascript, array, orientação-a-objetos

Tenho definido o objeto, e o array no escopo.

```
//Define o array que deve ser preenchido com os objetos
var itensList = [];

//Define os argumentos do objeto
var oItem = {
    Codig: 0,
    Desc: "",
    Unid: "KG",
    Quant: 0,
    Custo: 0,
    IL: "",
    Centro: "",
    Saldo: o
}
```

Então, para cada linha do DHTMLX Grid, inclui os resultados no objeto...

```
        //Para cada linha do grid, busca os resultados
        mygrid.forEachRow(function (id) {
            //Se o Codigo do item for maior que zero..
            if (mygrid.cells(id, 0).getValue() != 0) {
                // .. adiciona os valores ao objeto
                oItem.Codig = mygrid.cells(id, 0).getValue();
                oItem.Desc = mygrid.cells(id, 1).getValue();
                oItem.Unid = mygrid.cells(id, 2).getValue();
                oItem.Quant = mygrid.cells(id, 3).getValue();
                oItem.Custo = mygrid.cells(id, 4).getValue();
                oItem.IL = mygrid.cells(id, 5).getValue();
                oItem.Centro = mygrid.cells(id, 6).getValue();
                oItem.Saldo = mygrid.cells(id, 7).getValue();
                // Adiciona o objeto a lista
                itensList.push(oItem);
            }
        });
```

No final deste programa, se eu tenho duas linhas preenchidas no Grid, ele vai ter um array, com dois objetos, cada um com os parâmetros listados acima, mas, os dois ficam com os mesmso valores, os valores da última linha varrida pelo código, ou seja, dois objetos iguais, quando as linhas são diferentes. Debugando, vi que ao adicionar o objeto ao array com `itensList.push(oItem);`, ele faz o objeto que já estar lá ter os mesmos valores.

Como fazer com que cada objeto tenho os valores de cada linha?

Answer (score 3):

Isso acontece pq vc está inserindo o mesmo objeto no vetor. Ao alterar o valor do campo, ele altera as referências no vetor.

Uma maneira de resolver isso seria [clonar o objeto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/most-elegant-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object).

Uma outra maneira, mais simples, seria alterar a declaração da variável para  dentro do `if`.

```
mygrid.forEachRow(function (id) {
  //Se o Codigo do item for maior que zero..
  if (mygrid.cells(id, 0).getValue() != 0) {
    var oItem = {};

    // .. adiciona os valores ao objeto
    oItem.Codig = mygrid.cells(id, 0).getValue();
    oItem.Desc = mygrid.cells(id, 1).getValue();
    oItem.Unid = mygrid.cells(id, 2).getValue();
    oItem.Quant = mygrid.cells(id, 3).getValue();
    oItem.Custo = mygrid.cells(id, 4).getValue();
    oItem.IL = mygrid.cells(id, 5).getValue();
    oItem.Centro = mygrid.cells(id, 6).getValue();
    oItem.Saldo = mygrid.cells(id, 7).getValue();

    // Adiciona o objeto a lista
    itensList.push(oItem);
  }
});
```

Comment: Uma observação: na verdade o `var` pode ficar fora do `if`, no topo da função. Não existe "escopo do `if`" em js.

Comment: @bfavaretto De fato. Eu quis dizer "dentro" do if.

Answer (score 2):

O problema é que você está setando a mesma "instancia" do objeto item, sendo que ele vai ser modificado em todas as suas referências, já que ele está sendo declarado em um escopo global no javascript.

Em Javascript você não precisa declarar a estrutura do seu objeto, já que os objeto em javascript são dinâmico, você pode fazer apenas isso:

```
//Para cada linha do grid, busca os resultados
mygrid.forEachRow(function(id) {
    //Se o Codigo do item for maior que zero..
    if (mygrid.cells(id, 0).getValue() != 0) {
        // .. adiciona os valores ao objeto
        var oItem = new Object(); // cria um objeto novo (uma nova instância)
        oItem.Codig = mygrid.cells(id, 0).getValue();
        oItem.Desc = mygrid.cells(id, 1).getValue();
        oItem.Unid = mygrid.cells(id, 2).getValue();
        oItem.Quant = mygrid.cells(id, 3).getValue();
        oItem.Custo = mygrid.cells(id, 4).getValue();
        oItem.IL = mygrid.cells(id, 5).getValue();
        oItem.Centro = mygrid.cells(id, 6).getValue();
        oItem.Saldo = mygrid.cells(id, 7).getValue();
        // Adiciona o objeto a lista
        itensList.push(oItem);
    }
});
```

E remova a declaração do objeto:

```
//Define os argumentos do objeto
var oItem = {
    Codig: 0,
    Desc: "",
    Unid: "KG",
    Quant: 0,
    Custo: 0,
    IL: "",
    Centro: "",
    Saldo: o
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Você precisa limpar a variável `oItem`, mantenha a criação dela **fora do looping** e tente isso:

```
 //Para cada linha do grid, busca os resultados
        mygrid.forEachRow(function (id) {
            //Se o Codigo do item for maior que zero..
            if (mygrid.cells(id, 0).getValue() != 0) {
                // .. adiciona os valores ao objeto

                oItem = {}; // AQUI eu inicializo a variável

                oItem.Codig = mygrid.cells(id, 0).getValue();
                oItem.Desc = mygrid.cells(id, 1).getValue();
                oItem.Unid = mygrid.cells(id, 2).getValue();
                oItem.Quant = mygrid.cells(id, 3).getValue();
                oItem.Custo = mygrid.cells(id, 4).getValue();
                oItem.IL = mygrid.cells(id, 5).getValue();
                oItem.Centro = mygrid.cells(id, 6).getValue();
                oItem.Saldo = mygrid.cells(id, 7).getValue();
                // Adiciona o objeto a lista
                itensList.push(oItem);
            }
        });
```

**Ou para não perder as propriedades setadas inicialmente:**

```
 //Para cada linha do grid, busca os resultados
        mygrid.forEachRow(function (id) {
            //Se o Codigo do item for maior que zero..
            if (mygrid.cells(id, 0).getValue() != 0) {
                // .. adiciona os valores ao objeto

                var oItem = { // AQUI eu inicializo a variável
                  Codig: 0,
                  Desc: "",
                  Unid: "KG",
                  Quant: 0,
                  Custo: 0,
                  IL: "",
                  Centro: "",
                  Saldo: o
                } 

                oItem.Codig = mygrid.cells(id, 0).getValue();
                oItem.Desc = mygrid.cells(id, 1).getValue();
                oItem.Unid = mygrid.cells(id, 2).getValue();
                oItem.Quant = mygrid.cells(id, 3).getValue();
                oItem.Custo = mygrid.cells(id, 4).getValue();
                oItem.IL = mygrid.cells(id, 5).getValue();
                oItem.Centro = mygrid.cells(id, 6).getValue();
                oItem.Saldo = mygrid.cells(id, 7).getValue();
                // Adiciona o objeto a lista
                itensList.push(oItem);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Lembrando que a primeira opção considera que a variável já está declarada fora (senão, cria-se uma global implícita, má prática).

Comment: @bfavaretto Exato! Até complementei minha resposta :) Valeu.